# multi-step form in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So first the user submit a form and will appear a new window in which you have a 5 step page

my aim is to create one submission procedure   multi step form in which user can upload a file & etc..........

And so on.

It's much like an state-machine,

Don't know if my design is bad or if there's some correct way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer using Jquery to handle this (via hiding and showing divs after various steps), that way there is one easy form with the multiple steps.

Comment: one application i was also create with jquery but the problem is in that application the problem is i couldn't handle state

Comment: means when i am at 5th step and i go back so when next time i will start that page at a time it will start with 5 step not a first step so please give me solution

Answer (score 0):

Server side multi step forms, afaik, are not available with Rails as they do not gel well with the whole RESTful architecture.

However you can create a key-value data store (memcache, flat file or a table) which has a key and stores data as value at each step in a hash. Keep pushing the data back to the server after each step and storing it in this hash. To go back to previous steps, you can devise the URL of the form as ///. Key can be a UUID.